# Which nodejs v8 flags for benchmarking?

Tags: node.js, performance, benchmarking, v8

For comparison of different libraries with the same functionality, we compare their execution time. This works great. However, there are [v8 flags](https://flaviocopes.com/node-runtime-v8-options/) that impact execution time and skew results.

Some flags that are relevant are: `--predictable`, `--always-opt`, `--no-opt`, `--minimal`.

**Question:** Which v8 flags should typically be set for running *a meaningful* benchmarks? What are the tradeoffs?

---

Edit: The problem is that a benchmark typically runs the same code over and over to get a good average. This might lead to v8 optimizing code, which it would typically not optimize.

Comment: _The problem ... might lead to v8 optimizing code which it would typically not optimize._ - this sounds like a conjecture without supporting evidence.

Comment: Why do you think this is not a problem? It leads to comparisons that are meaningless for real-world usage. I guess it depends on what the purpose of the benchmark is.

Comment: _Why do you think this is not a problem?_ - because you don't provide the details or reproduction of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V8 developer here. **You should definitely run benchmarks with the default configuration.** It is the responsibility of the benchmark to be realistic. An unrealistic benchmark cannot be made meaningful with engine flags. (And yes, there are many many unrealistic and/or otherwise meaningless snippets of code out there that people call "benchmarks". Remember, if you can't measure a difference with a realistic benchmark, then any unmeasurable difference that might exist is irrelevant.)

In particular:

> `--predictable`

Absolutely not. Detrimental to performance. Changes behavior in unrealistic ways. Meant for debugging certain things, and for helping fuzzers find reproducible test cases (at the expense of being somewhat unrealistic), not for anything related to performance testing.

> `--always-opt`

Absolutely not. Contrary to what a naive reader of this flag's name might think, this does **not** improve performance, on the contrary; it mostly causes V8 to waste a bunch of CPU cycles on useless work. This flag is barely ever useful at all; it can sometimes flush out weird corner case bugs in the compilation pipeline, but most of the time it just creates pointless work for V8 developers by creating artificial situations that never occur in practice.

> `--no-opt`

Absolutely not. Turns off all optimizations. Totally unrealistic.

> `--minimal`

That's not a V8 flag I've ever heard of. So yeah, sure, pass it along, it won't do anything (beyond printing an "unknown flag" warning), so at least it won't break anything.

Comment: Writing a realistic benchmark is definitely not trivial and I was hoping there was some sort of cheat code here. But it makes perfect sense that there isn't. I just have to sit down and do this properly I guess (possibly spawning new v8 instances for each test run). Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: @vincent I'd be surprised if spawning hundreds of new instances per second was anywhere close to realistic behavior.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. A test should emulate realistic behavior. But because of variability in execution time we need to run it many times to get a good average. Each of those runs should be independent and a v8 "cold start".

Comment: You should "cold start" the test every couple of milliseconds if and only if your real app "cold starts" every couple of milliseconds. Or, you know, just go ahead and waste your time measuring unrealistic things, that's up to you.

Comment: Haha, fair enough. Ultimately it's very hard to predict real world usage for a general library (=

Answer (score 2):

Using default flags seems like the best way to me, since that's what most people will use.

Comment: I've added a note to my question to explain why this might not be a good idea.

Comment: @vincent It rather sounds like the benchmarks you're thinking of running might not be a good idea.