# How to avoid CPU optimization in JavaScript benchmark

Tags: javascript, optimization, benchmarking

Sometimes we should benchmarking two similar algorithms, but if we execute them continuously, CPU optimization may affect the result. (From I know)

I created three benchmarking files, one file of them contains other two benchmarking tasks.

```js
// bench.js

console.time('bench1')
for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    // do some things
}
console.timeEnd('bench1')

console.time('bench2')
for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    // do some things
}
console.timeEnd('bench2')

// bench1.js

console.time('bench1')
for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    // do some things
}
console.timeEnd('bench1')

// bench2.js

console.time('bench2')
for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    // do some things
}
console.timeEnd('bench2')
```

In fact, all these task are same. In other words, **it expected to get similar benchmarking results from bench1 and bench2**.

But executing `bench.js`, I found the task which run later spends less time in most times.

Then I execute `bench1.js`, and execute `bench2.js` after a while. I get silimar results from them. That's expected.

---

Results on my machine:

```bash
> node .\benchmark\bench.js

bench1: 96.419ms
bench2: 41.822ms

> node .\benchmark\bench1.js

bench1: 96.293ms

> node .\benchmark\bench2.js

bench2: 97.805ms
```

---

From I know, I think it because of CPU optimization.

So, how to avoid these factors in practice? Or my speculate is wrong?

Comment: Instead of avoiding CPU optimization most benchmarking code try to **only test** CPU optimized code. After all, it is the optimized run that is important. They do this by running the benchmark a few times and discarding the results before running the real benchmark. This is called "warmup" (https://engineering.appfolio.com/appfolio-engineering/2017/5/2/what-about-warmup)

Comment: @slebetman I have tried "warmup". My practice is ignore the first quintile of benchmarkings. The impact seems reduced but it still exists. Maybe I should ignore more benchmarkings?

Answer (score 1):

Use a benchmarking tool such as [`hyperfine`](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) to run your `bench1.js` and `bench2.js`.

It will average out outliers etc.

<del>You can also run with `--jitless` flag to try and tell Node to do less optimization still (see `node --v8-options` for more)</del> but that's apparently **not a good idea.**

Comment: *You can also run with --jitless* - But **don't**.  Unless you really know what you're doing, and perhaps are trying to benchmark the cold-startup performance of something.  See an answer from a V8 developer (jmk) on [Which nodejs v8 flags for benchmarking?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73057889)

Comment: @PeterCordes Great point and link, thanks :)

Comment: I'm using a benchmarking library called `benchmarkjs` now, but I still don't know how benchmarking library resolved this problem.